# Why does `\coordinate` fail but `\node` succeed at an intersection of two paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

The following code fails:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,rotate around={45:(2.3,5)}] (2.3,5) rectangle ++(4,0.3) ++(0,-0.15) coordinate (p2);
\draw[name path=1st] (1.8,4)--(1.8,6);
\draw[name path=2nd] (p2)--+(225:5);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=1st and 2nd}] (i12) at (intersection-1);
\fill[red] (i12) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But if I substitute `\node[name intersections={of=1st and 2nd}] (i12) at (intersection-1) {};` for `\coordinate[name intersections={of=1st and 2nd}] (i12) at (intersection-1);`, I get what I want:

[image]

Why does the first method fail? Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you could also just do `\path[name intersections={of=1st and 2nd,by={i12}}];` instead of using `\node`/`\coordinate`.

Comment: According to page 218 in pgfmanual, `coordinate` is a  “light-weight” node. I suppose that this means that `coordinate` definition is limited compared with `node`.   The solution proposed by Torbjørn T. is the one proposed in documentation, but if you insist in using your syntax to obtain a `coordinate` node, you could also use: `\node[coordinate, name intersections={of=1st and 2nd}] (i12) at (intersection-1) {};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In essence, `\coordinate` is an alias for `\node[shape=coordinate]`.  Looking through `tikz.code.tex`, it would appear that `\coordinate[options]` becomes `\node[shape=coordinate,options]` and so your `\coordinate` syntax *ought* to work.  I'm not entirely sure why it doesn't (and my investigation time is a bit short today), but the following code *does* work, which I would say shows that the intention is that the original syntax should work and that that it doesn't might be considered a bug (though I'd investigate further to see exactly where it breaks down before filing it).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364184/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,rotate around={45:(2.3,5)}] (2.3,5) rectangle ++(4,0.3) ++(0,-0.15) coordinate (p2);
\draw[name path=1st] (1.8,4)--(1.8,6);
\draw[name path=2nd] (p2)--+(225:5);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=1st and 2nd},name=i12,at=(intersection-1)]; 
\fill[red] (i12) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(A bit of cutting and pasting shows that it is the `at` part that causes the problem.  Putting `at=(intersection-1)` as an option works, but `at (intersection-1)` afterwards doesn't.)

---

*Update*: I see the problem now.  When you use the `at (intersection-1)` syntax then TikZ calculates the location of `(intersection-1)` at the point when it parses that option.  This is, as @TeXnician says, a problem because `intersection-1` has not yet been calculated.  But when `at=(intersection-1)` is passed as an option, this is not calculated until much later in the process whereupon the path intersection has been calculated.

Nodes are different here because the processing for nodes is a bit different to that for coordinates.  Essentially, the `\coordinate` is doing some pre-processing before shipping off its stuff to the `\node`.  This is necessary, but does mean that things get processed in a slightly different order than for `\node`s.

Answer (score 6):

One version would be to use

```
\coordinate[name intersections={of=1st and 2nd,by=i12}];
\fill[red] (i12) circle (2pt);
```

which names the point using `intersections`. Another option is to use

```
\coordinate[name intersections={of=1st and 2nd}];
\fill[red] (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
```

or

```
\path[name intersections={of=1st and 2nd}];
\coordinate (i12) at (intersection-1);
\fill[red] (i12) circle (2pt);
```

which uses the internal name for the intersection.

Your code does not work, because the intersection is not known to TikZ at this stage, so it cannot assign the coordinate to the point.

Comment: But why does it work with `\node` instead of `\coordinate`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Only speculation, but probably because of the processing of optional arguments (I'm currently reading the TikZ manual searching for it).

Comment: I still can only guess (after reading the manual) that nodes preprocess optional arguments other than coordinates. But probably we should wait for someone who is able to really answer this.